# I went to the doctor's

Tags: meaning, possessives

I have run across such a sentence:

> Yesterday I was ill, so I went to the doctor's.

What is the function of possessive here, that is **doctor's**?

Comment: Usually, it's **"I went to a doctor"** or **"I visited a doctor"**

Comment: I would say it's short for "the doctor's office."

Comment: @ SovereignSun "a doctor" is fine if you mean any doctor, but use of the definite article "the" would be more common here, since the reference is probably to a specific doctor.

Comment: @Vekzhivi Yeh, you are right.

Comment: see https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/73638/3463

Answer (score 6):

This type of possessive is commonly used to refer to a particular shop, or something similar to a shop like a doctor's surgery or a dental clinic. The pattern being used is: [somebody's] [place] (e.g. butcher's shop) and the unnecessary [place] is often left off for brevity. You will often hear the following used:

I'm going to the:

- doctor's (doctor's surgery)
- dentist's (dental clinic)
- butcher's (butcher's shop)
- baker's (bakery)
- (green)grocer's (grocer's shop)
- barber's (barber's shop)
- hairdresser's (hairdressing salon)

Comment: We use it in the US, too...

Comment: @Catija Thanks, I wasn't sure whether it was a British thing, I'll remove BrE from my answer.