# I'm going to the dry cleaner's - why the apostrophe S?

Tags: apostrophe

"Dave's car" means the "car of Dave".

But why do we need the apostrophe S in: I'm going to the dry cleaner's ?

Is there another way to say this phrase? For example: I'm going to the establishment of the dry cleaner? (that sounds completely off to me).

Comment: What is the source?  Perhaps it is a misprint?  Even native speakers make mistakes, more often than you might think.

Comment: See e.g. *[I went to the doctor's](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131126)* and *[What does the butcher's (meaning the butcher's shop) become in the plural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70976)* Of potential interest at EL&U is *[Store names & possessive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14796)* which covers the same principle with proper nouns.

Comment: *I'm going to the dry cleaner's* is kind of like "Which car are you looking at?  **I'm looking at Dave's.**"  You don't always have to use a noun with a possessive.

Answer (score 5):

When the shop is named after the owner it is fairly common to use a possessive to describe it:

A butcher is a person.  A butcher's (shop) is a place to buy meat.

A dry cleaner is a person who cleans clothes.  A dry cleaner's is the shop where he works.

Now there is quite a lot of variation here. Some people will write and say

> I'm going to the dry cleaner.
>   I'm going to the dry cleaner's.
>   I'm going to the dry cleaners.

All three can be considerd to be correct.